# How to create an integer-for-loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, for-loop

I have a variable "x" in my view. I need to display some code "x" number of times.

I basically want to set up a loop like this:

```
for i = 1 to x
  do something on (i)
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you're doing this in your erb view (for Rails), be mindful of the `<%` and `<%=` differences. What you'd want is:

```
<% (1..x).each do |i| %>
  Code to display using <%= stuff %> that you want to display    
<% end %>
```

For plain Ruby, you can refer to: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Answer (score 103):

```
x.times do |i|
    something(i+1)
end
```

Comment: This is the Rails way

Comment: The first iteration will be i=0. The `i+1` in this example effectively results in 1-based iteration, as the OP requested.

Answer (score 15):

```
for i in 0..max
   puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

[All Ruby loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm)

Comment: Although the other solutions work, this is the most correct answer since it uses a for loop.

Comment: This is the better solution to do a FOR LOOP in Ruby

Answer (score 11):

You can perform a simple `each` loop on the range from 1 to `x´:

```
(1..x).each do |i|
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 11):

Try Below Simple Ruby Magics :)

```
(1..x).each { |n| puts n }
x.times { |n| puts n }
1.upto(x) { |n| print n }
```